Remove tar foundation primer before applying hydraulic cement?
I'm fixing a foundation crack. Cleaning up before filling with quikrete hydraulic cement. However there is alot of old tar foundation primer on there. Will the hydraulic cement adhere to it, or do I need to remove it? It's a lot of work to remove.

Hydraulic cement expands during curing/drying.  It also usually requires a reverse V shape, smaller at the surface and widening out the deeper you go into the crack.  The tar/sealer should be gone from the crack by the time you are ready to apply the cement.  Read the instructions.

Thanks... For the tar/sealer, it's not referenced in the instructions. It's obviously not "in" the crack, but all around it. The cement needs to be smoothed out a few inches either side of the crack. This is where it would sit on the tar if I don't remove.

Mineral spirits/gasoline/diesel fuel should clean/soften tar.  Smoking is highly not recommended when cleaning, unless a youtuber who makes hold my beer, watch this vids.

are you going to use a fiberglass tape and impregnate with tar after patched?

i am not even sure I'd hydraulic cement a crack unless it was massive.  https://rexoseal.ca/product/rexoseal-reinforcing-membrane/?attribute_size=5%22+x+50%27&gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQjw6oi4BhD1ARIsAL6pox20axGmnFgBmQeHQbBokY7vXuqN9EirKLSHNRVjjiettVj_3FEE6TUaAubDEALw_wcB

The crack is about 3/4" at its widest part. I've never heard of using tape. Is there a positive of one vs. the other?
